# Add legend from raster catalog? ArcGis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, legend, raster-catalog

Does anyone have a solution on how to add the legend from a raster catalog?

It does not show up, either in version 10.1 or 10.2.1. It only shows the name "Legend".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do. Do you want a legend that lists the rasters in the catalog, one that just shows the raster catalog layer, or one that shows value ranges/classification that is common to all rasters in the catalog?

This [ESRI Knowledge Base article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/25165) covers getting the catalog layer to show in the legend.

> This article assumes that the legend has already been created and
>   exists in the layout, and is a workaround for the Legend Wizard which
>   does not allow for this modification.
>
> 1. Select the legend item in the layout and right click it.
> 2. Select Properties from the context menu.
> 3. Select the Items tab.
> 4. Right click the raster catalog name in the Legend Items list.
> 5. Select Properties.
> 6. Select the General tab.
> 7. Select Show Item Name.
> 8. Select OK in the Legend Item Properties.
> 9. Select OK in the Legend Properties.

To show the value ranges/classification in a legend, this [ERSI forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/60623-Creating-a-Legend-for-a-Raster-Catalog) has a workaround that selects one example raster to create and show a legend that applies to all rasters in the catalog. It relies on all of those rasters having a common classification scale. There is also an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Huc&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Imagery&sort=comments) to add that functionality natively into the program for raster catalogs.