# Creating Time-series (Temporal) Map of NDVI?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, time, ndvi

Is there a best practice for a cartographer to create a Time-series or Temporal Map ? I have 83 of the NDVI in an imagine format and should I converted them to polygons and populated them and display them in Monthly series as a field ?

This is the one I will be doing a similar to this but it will be mainly the NDVI and how do I put the legend ?

[NDVI Map using Time-series](https://www.google.com/search?source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Gh2fU6apCvjMsQTjv4DICw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoATgU&biw=1680&bih=935&q=Map%20Time%20series%20or%20temporal%20How%20to#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=G1mUZ1-a-Vso_M%253A;1dUlWJ2zolrOZM;http%253A%252F%252Fproceedings.esri.com%252Flibrary%252Fuserconf%252Fproc02%252Fpap0593%252Fp05931.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fgis.stackexchange.com%252Fquestions%252Ftagged%252Ftime;1214;790)

Comment: I don't see a need to convert to vector, but I may not understand the issue you're trying to solve. As per your [other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93935/creating-a-time-series-ndvi-map) do you want one map/image that changes over time or with a control, or a series of 83 different images? The legend would be similar to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99827/add-legend-from-raster-catalog-arcgis-10-1) and your previous; make sure they are all classified the same, then select one to create the legend from since the same legend applies to all.

Comment: Chris, I wasn't sure what to do. I research a little bit and thought either way can do that but it can be consumed my time doing that convert to vector. I want the one with series of 83 different images. How do I do that ?

Comment: Give me an example, I have 83 images here but they are by month by year so for example i have 4 images that are in 2004 and they are in different month.

Comment: I have years from 2004 to 2013 but for the months it varies by the year

Comment: @Chris W, Are you saying to have each image overlay each other with different month ?

Comment: @ChrisW ,so meaning that on one poster, you put each one image from Jan, and then Feb, and March and etc on side by side for one year, for example, 2004 and then the next year 2005 do the same thing ?

Comment: I've converted the bulk of my comments to an answer (which I can edit if needed) because the comment chain was getting long. You should probably edit your original question to include the information from your comments as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two critical factors to suggesting a solution - target format and actual data sequence. For electronic format, I'd animate it via movie or controls. You could create something where you pick which image is visible (or even two side-by-side). There are many ways to implement that. But if the target format is paper based (or even static electronic like a simple pdf) then it's more a layout question. And you have to consider how your audience will use or consume this information (comparing a month year to year, comparing the months over the course of a year, just as individual references, etc).

If format is a book/paper, I might suggest one year per two page spread (or six images per page). That's still 14 pages of maps, and flipping back and forth to do any comparison would be difficult. From the amount of data you have, you could also make each two page spread a single month - all of your January images on two pages, February on the next two pages, etc.

If a poster, I'd try to keep years/months aligned. So for your data each of 10 rows on the poster would be a year, and each of 12 columns would be the same month. In the case of your data, you'd have 37 holes in the grid for the months you have no image, which is about 30% of your poster being whitespace. With that many missing months, it may not be as useful to be able to easily compare from year to year.